# Jquery: How to dynamically SHOW image using the "value" of <input type="file"> Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering whether there is a way to dynamically display an image that a user just uploaded to the input type="file" field.

For example, so far I have the following code:

**image_upload.html**

```
<form id ="image_upload_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id ="id_iamge" type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<div id="image_view">
    <img id="uploaded_image">
</div>
```

**upload.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_image").change(file_select);
});

function file_select(event) {
    $("#uploaded_image").attr("src", $("#id_image").val());
}
```

So I basically want to show the image that the user just uploaded on the  Field.

Of course, I know I can easily view the image if the user already SUBMITTED the form, and when the image is already inside my Database server.

However, I want to preview the image BEFORE the image is submitted into the database server.

In order to do this, I guess I have to find out the PATH of the Image in the Uploader's own computer and then set that "Local path" as the "src" of the image.

Is there a way to fetch this LOCAL PATH of the image that the user just submitted?

(My Javascript code above obviously didn't work, since it just sets the NAME of the image file, not the absolute Path, as the "src".  For example, when I run that code and upload an image, I get this:

**The Result:**

```
<img id="uploaded_image" src="random_image.jpg" />
```

which doesn't show anything.

Comment: You can do this using the HTML5 file api.

Comment: That sounds awful! Better upload the image to a temporary folder, present it for preview, then send it to DB or delete it.

Comment: The file input - for security reasons - returns a fake path as the file name, like `C:\\fakepath\\filename.png`. Also, the file is not transferred to the server, which would make it impossible for the webpage to load it.

Comment: @Robert Yeah I know that's the best way,,, but wouldn't that waste the memory of my database server??

Comment: Here's a bootstrap component to get you started: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

Comment: @DJDavid98 So I must save it to a temporary folder in my database server first in order to do that, right???

Comment: Or, you could Google it like the rest of us do? There is actually an exact example of what you want to do on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: You don't need to put your image in the DB, it gets saved to the server's filesystem first. Putting it into the DB is another step!

Comment: @Rober you don't have to get any server involved you can handle the file on the client side using File api

Comment: a simple example using html5 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9pTW6/1/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at this sample, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting "TypeError: $(...).files is undefined" Error.. I'm using the latest version of Chrome, so I'm pretty sure it supports HTML5.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code. It will work:

```
<!-- Java script code, use jquery library. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showimagepreview(input) 
    {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
      {
        var filerdr = new FileReader();
        filerdr.onload = function(e) {
            $('#imgDisplayarea').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<form>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="imgShow" id="imgShow" onchange="imagePreview(this)" />
    </div>
    <img id="imgDisplayarea"/>
</form>
```